# Rules applying to linking to itunes from iOS application

Tags: ios, hyperlink, itunes, hig

I link to various itunes products from my application but I can't seem to find any rules/documentation covering this. Am I allowed to use the itunes logo and is there anything special I need to do in the mechanics of linking.

Answer (score 2):

See section 8.1 here for advice on trademarks:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

As for linking to iTunes products, I imagine you're using the `openURL:` call of `UIApplication` to do this, which is sufficient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked there already and through the HIG. It seems logical that Apple would allow you to use an iTunes logo/icon to link through as it would reassure users, but I see nothing to endorse or prohibit it.

Comment: That is correct - I imagine you'll be fine, else you'll find out when your app is reviewed. Best of luck :)

Comment: unsure why the downvote - must be whoever voted to close this as off topic... sigh